# Pirate Game in Maths - Solve it with C#

Tags: c#, math, console-application, primes

I am trying to solve the following problem:

> Some pirates have a chest full of treasure (gold coins)
>
> It is late in the evening, so they decide to split it up in the morning
>
> But, one of the pirates wakes up in the middle of the night concerned that
>   the other pirates will steal his share so he decides to go divide the
>   treasure himself.
>
> He divides it into equal shares (one for each pirate). There is one
>   coin left over, which he throws overboard. He takes his share, puts the other shares back in the chest,
>   and returns to his cabin.
>
> Another pirate wakes up and does the same thing. Yes, there is still
>   one extra coin. Yes, he throws that coin overboard.
>
> ... Each pirate does this once during the night (yes, there is an
>   extra coin and they throw it overboard each time) , and the next
>   morning they wake up and divide the treasure into equal shares. There
>   is one left over which they throw overboard. They each take their
>   share and live happily ever after.
>
> Given the number of pirates, what is the smallest number of coins that
>   could have been in the treasure chest originally?

I tried the following, but any number greater than 8 brings it to its knees:

```
class Program
    {
        static long _input;
        static long _timesDivided;
        static string _output;

        static void Main()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Enter the number of Pirates: ");

            var isValidInput = long.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out _input);

            if (!isValidInput)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Please enter a valid number");
                Console.ReadKey();
                return;
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Caculating minimum treasure...\r\n \r\n");

            _timesDivided = _input + 1;

            var answer = CalculateTreasure();

            if (answer > 0)
                _output = string.Format("The minimum treasure is {0}", answer);
            else
                _output = "There was an error, please try another number";

            Console.WriteLine(_output);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        private static long CalculateTreasure()
        {
            long result = 0;

            try
            {
                while (true)
                {
                    result++;

                    while (true)
                    {
                        if (result % _input == 1)
                        {
                            break;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            result++;
                        }
                    }

                    long treasure = result;

                    for (long i = 0; i < _timesDivided; i++)
                    {
                        var remainder = treasure % _input;

                        if (remainder != 1)
                        {
                            break;
                        }

                        var share = (treasure - remainder) / _input;

                        if (i == (_timesDivided - 1))
                        {
                            treasure = (treasure - (share * _input));

                            if (treasure == 1)
                                return result;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            treasure = (treasure - share) - 1;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                //log exception here
                return 0;
            }
        }
    }
```

I am fairly certain that every number must be a prime number, so I have also attempted the above with that in mind. However, I have not been able to figure out an efficient formula for solving this. My maths is simply too weak

EDIT

Thanks to the video Fr3d mentioned, I now have this for my CalculateTreasure method:

```
private static long CalculateTreasure()
        {
            try
            {
                long result = (long)Math.Pow((double)_input, (double)_timesDivided);

                while (true)
                {
                    result--;

                    while (true)
                    {
                        if (result % _input == 1)
                        {
                            break;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            result--;
                        }
                    }

                    long treasure = result;

                    for (long i = 0; i < _timesDivided; i++)
                    {
                        var remainder = treasure % _input;

                        if (remainder != 1)
                        {
                            break;
                        }

                        var share = (treasure - remainder) / _input;

                        if (i == (_timesDivided - 1))
                        {
                            treasure = (treasure - (share * _input));

                            if (treasure == 1)
                                return result;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            treasure = (treasure - share) - 1;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                //log exception here
                return 0;
            }
        }
```

It is much improved, but still not 100% optimal

Comment: I am not sure what you mean. But for 2 pirates its 7 coins, 3 pirates the answer is 79, for 4 its 1021, for 5 its 15621

Comment: Shouldn't 3 pirates be 22 coins? And then 4 pirates would be 22*4+1=89, and 5 pirates is 89*5+1=446 and so on

Comment: @user3574076 2 pirates with 7 coins? the first one get 3, remain 4, the second one get 2, where is the extra one?

Comment: You should post this on the puzzling SE, It sounds like it has a simple mathematical answer. You could work backwards from the end. The n pirates must have n+1 coins.

Comment: @xwhyLikeThis 7 coins, you throw one, u get 6. You split to 3 and 3. the 1 is lost forever. However the smaller number is actually 3. Technically, you could even say the solution for 2 pirates is 1.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=U9qU20VmvaU Try watching this video

Comment: @Fr3d that video really helped, however perhaps I didn't quite understand it all. It seems that an easy way to do it is just do n^(n+1) and then send it to my console app, and work backwards in the while loop rather than forward. As n^(n+1) appears to get the prime number after the one that is the correct answer

Comment: @Ewan the thing is (watch the really great video) the don't have n+1 coins - as you are dealing with integers this assumption is sadly not valid

Comment: I believe this sequence is the answer: https://oeis.org/A173468

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I found the correct formula:

```
using System;
using System.Numerics;

namespace PirateCoins
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int n = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.WriteLine(GetTreasure(n));
        }
        static BigInteger GetTreasure(int n)
        {
            BigInteger result = BigInteger.Pow(n, n + 1) - (n - 1);
            return result;
        }
    }
}
```

This is based from a sequence which was given 2 -> 7, 3 -> 79, 4 -> 1021, 5 -> 15621 .

Comment: sorry got this wrong for a moment and yeah for n=5,3 and 2 (with a bit strange last round) it works - and of course this is the one from the video - but can you explain why this works in general? (because this is the interesting question left ;))

Comment: there n^(n+1) shares, from the last 2 shares there were coins given to the monkey :) I'm not sure why it works just fiddled with the answers a bit and the correct sequence you wrote.

Comment: this is much better, turns out its quite simple, but the overall maths is indeed somewhat more complex

Comment: How is 2 pirates solved with 7?  First pirate would split 7 into 3,3,1.  He'd take 3, throw away 1, and then he'd put 3 back.  The second pirate would split 3 into 1,1,1.  He'd take 1, throw away 1, and put 1 back.  Now in the morning they don't have enough left to perform the procedure one last time.

Comment: I believe the correct answer for 2 pirates is 15.  First pirate splits 15 into 7,7,1.  He takes 7, throws 1 away, and puts 7 back.  Second pirate splits 7 into 3,3,1.  He takes 3, throws 1 away, and puts 3 back.  In the morning, they split 3 into 1,1,1.  Each gets one and they throw out the last one.

Comment: This is quite a good point, however they actually split 0,0,1 so 7 could be a possible solution. It is the matter how you define a problem.

Comment: Also you can solve this by adding 2 in the exponent instead of 1.